# Capitilize Alt/Title Tag in Image HTML, Reorder HTML Output

Tags: images, uploads

Someone kindly wrote the two pieces of code at the end of this post for me a few years ago. I'm currently trying to modify them but am not having much luck after an hour of Googling and breaking Wordpress over and over.

Right now, the first code takes an upload-file-name.jpg and change it to "uploaded file name" for the image's alt and title tags. The second code adds `rel="highslide"` and `class="highslide"` to each image's link. This is what it outputs when you insert an image into Wordpress:

```
<a class="highslide" href="http://domain.com/wp/uploads/0215/the-name-of-the-file.jpg" rel="highslide"><img class=" alignright" title="the name of the file" src="http://domain.com/wp/uploads/0215/the-name-of-the-file-217x200.jpg" alt="the name of the file" width="217" height="200" /></a>
```

What I want to do is capitilize the first letter of each word in the image's alt and title tags so that it outputs to "The Name Of The File."

For the link HTML, I'd also like to move `class="highslide"` to the end so that it goes in the order of `href`, `rel`, then `class`. I couldn't figure out how to change the order of anything even when switching pieces of code around. I know it sounds super nitpicky to reorder it, but my writers and I do a lot of manual HTML editing, and this order is what we're used to doing in Wordpress.

For the image HTML, I'd like to do it in the order of `src`, `height`, `width`, `alt`, `title`, then `class`.

I hope others can use these cool codes too! Thank you!

```
/** USE FILENAME FOR ALT AND TITLE TAGS WHEN INSERTING */
function wpse_120228_seomadness($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {

    $alttitle = str_replace('-', ' ', $alt);
    $img      = get_image_tag($id, $alttitle, $alttitle, $align, $size);
    $html     = '<a href="' . esc_attr($url) . '">' . $img . '</a>';

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wpse_120228_seomadness', 10, 9 );


/** ADD HIGHSLIDE CLASSES TO HYPERLINKED IMAGES */
function add_highslide_attr( $html ) {
    preg_match_all('/(<a[^>]*>)(.*)/i', $html, $result);

    if( !isset($result) || !isset($result[1][0]) || ! $result[1][0] )
        return $html;

    $anchor = $result[1][0];

    if( strstr($anchor, 'rel=') )
        $anchor = str_replace('rel="', 'rel="highslide ', $anchor);
    else
        $anchor = str_replace('href=', 'rel="highslide" href=', $anchor);

    if( strstr($anchor, 'class=') )
        $anchor = str_replace('class="', 'class="highslide ', $anchor);
    else
        $anchor = str_replace('href=', 'class="highslide" href=', $anchor);

    $html = $anchor . $result[2][0];

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'add_highslide_attr', 10 );
```

Comment: Hi Jon! Actually these are multiple questions. For the future: Please post each individual question as separate questions. Also have a look at [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a partial answer.

In your first function you may use **ucwords()** PHP function:

```
$alttitle = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $alt ) );
```

Second task is more complicated. I don't have a ready solution for you but the direction should be to extract attributes and values from HTML (playing with **preg_match()**), store them in variables and concatenate in a different order.

Now a side note. Personally I prefer to filter output of the content than modifying the code that is sent to editor. If my mods (for example class name or HTML structure) will go in conflict with some plugin or theme I can easily adjust them as they are not stored in the database.